# What data do we share in real time Multiplayer game

Tags: android, game-engine, multiplayer

I am learning game developement and was thinking of creating a real time 2 player game for android. It needs to have simultanious game play of tow players on two android devices , the one like this: [Gurrilla bob](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.angrymobgames.guerrillabob)

Now I want to know is there some tutorial over what should be shared in real time between the two devices for the games running on each of them to be in sync ? I do not want to know the network implementation.

Is it that

The game runs on one main device and the screen is shared on the other device and it just reports input events to the main game.?

The two devices share Physical world details(position of bodies , forces on them , their positions) or something similar(I am just guessing)?

Or is it something totally different ?

Comment: Here is a game [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611201/Make-realtime-multiplayer-AndEngine-games) you can view on getting realtime interaction between Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

The range of "data we share" really depends on the level of security you desire. In a massively multiplayer online game (Which is a bit different because it has a server between the players), the data shared could range between the following, from the most **secure**:

- The user *input* itself. The client sends the server what the user does - he tapped the screen to shoot, he swiped the screen to move, etc... *The server* processes the input and decides whether to respond to it (If it's legal input) or not (If it has been modified, I.E hacks and cheats). This gives a lot of work to the server - All processing is done on it, and it has to report to all its client what happens and when. However, it blocks pretty much most if not all hacking/malicious input options, making your game very secure.

To the most **insecure**

- The user input *consequences*: The client itself processes the input, and reports to the server what the input caused, its consequences. For example, if the user tapped the screen to shoot, the client calculates the bullet direction and sends to the server "I shot a bullet at this time and that direction". This allows clients to send misinformation - A client could send "I shot 100 bullets", which means you'll have to add many checks on the server, to make sure players don't cheat

Now, since you are neither talking about a MMO, nor about a game whose security is important (After all, it runs on an Android and few are those who know how to hack applications, and you weren't about to publish it anyway), I feel kinda stupid for writing that much when it's not necessary, but I hope you got some of it.

Back to your problem - When talking about 2-player game, especially on a phone, real-time and network efficiency are the most important factors. So we can wipe off the option of "Sharing screens" as streaming videos is not that fast or network efficient.

I think the best solution will be that both devices respond to input and send the consequences to each other. This way, users won't experience latency, or just very little. You'll have to handle special cases that latency may cause (For example, when talking about shooting games - If player A shot and killed player B, but player B lagged and took 5 seconds to receive that consequence, and meanwhile before his death he shot and killed player A, player A shouldn't die.)